# how to avoid double navbar in expo router?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I'm new in a mobile development and don't understand why it works this way.
I want to have different stacks, so when I push a new stack in each tab, the tab bar remains at the bottom.

[folder's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYKWW.png)
[double navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJRTe.png)

I'm using expo sdk 49 and expo router 2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a navigator in your app/_layout.tsx and also in your app/home/_layout.tsx
You kann hide the header in your app/_layout.tsx and only show the other header.
You can do this by adding the "headerShown: false" option in your navigator.

Something like this should work:

```
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="home" options={{}} />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/stack/#header-buttons